# ¿Por qué activa esto un subjuntivo?

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo

Estaba viendo un video cuando ví esta frase "podeis hacer que el video se reproduzca mas despacio en la configuracion de la velocidad"

Estoy confundido porque donde esta el lugar donde hay un disprador para un subjuntivo? Particularmente antes de 'que'

Gracias :)

Answer (score 4):

Lo que dispara el subjuntivo en este caso es la presencia de la frase *"hacer que..."*. En este ejemplo está subordinado a *poder* (*"podéis hacer que..."*), pero no hace ninguna diferencia. En este caso *hacer* significa más o menos lo mismo que *obligar, forzar*. La frase *"causar que..."* significa casi lo mismo y también dispara un subjuntivo.

*"Hacer que el video se reproduzca más despacio."* = "Forzar al video a reproducirse más despacio."

El subjuntivo aparece en esta clase de frases porque implica un deseo, una situación irreal y un objetivo o intención de cambiar. El video está reproduciéndose rápido; el deseo de quien habla es indicar cómo se puede cambiar eso. Es parecido a lo que ocurre con los verbos *querer*, *desear*, *lograr* y otros: todos requieren un subjuntivo cuando los sigue una subordinada (*quiero que el video se detenga; deseo que él se vaya; logré que me devolvieran el dinero*, etc.).